# Jquery .load() doesn't seem to be working in firefox

Tags: jquery

I've tried to find the answer to this by searching through Stackoverflow, and I've found a lot of closely related answers, but none seem to give me quite what I'm looking for. Most are much more complicated scenarios and just don't apply. Anyhow, what I'm doing is calling to a certain page of my site using the url, and then as well identifying a specific element on the page to be loaded into another div #getter. This script works flawlessly in IE and Chrome, but I'm having no luck at all with Firefox. Any ideas? Here is the code:

```
<script>
$("#getter").load("http://$domain/member/?show=feed .content");
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but still no go. Thank you for trying to help. I got the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code (with out domain):

```
<script>
$("#getter").load("/member/?show=feed .content");
</script>
```

Comment: $domain - is php variable. Also you can try $("#getter").load("http://". $domain ."/member/?show=feed .content");

Comment: That last one didn't seem to work when I tried it, but the first one did. I wonder if $domain is also a variable of Asp too possibly. I think that's what the platform I'm working on uses.

Answer (score 1):

i thinks its better to put code in

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#getter").load("http://$domain/member/?show=feed .content");
});
```

there might be cause its get called before dom get loaded

Answer (score 0):

If you need absolute path and have to have a php variable, try

```
$("#getter").load("http://<?php echo $domain;?>/member/?show=feed .content");
```

Although, it isn't a great idea to mix php and js, sometimes one just has to.

Comment: Thanks, this also worked and will come in handy for a couple of other scenarios I'm facing. :)